# Change redis log file's path

Tags: centos, redis, systemctl

I just installed redis cluster overs 3 centos 7 VM using yum.
When trying to change the log file path and dir , redis did not start using systemctl 
and output is

```
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 redis-server[21278]: *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 redis-server[21278]: Reading the configuration file, at line 170
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 redis-server[21278]: >>> 'logfile /opt/redis.log'
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 redis-server[21278]: Can't open the log file: Permission denied
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 systemd[1]: redis.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis persistent key-value database.
Jun 18 16:53:11 v-mht-db01 systemd[1]: Unit redis.service entered failed state.
```

Even if I change the conf file path I have the permission denied exception unless the directory have all permission.

Answer (score 0):

** Changing this is probably not a great idea ** 
You are likely not to have log rotate manage your log files etc by doing this.

As far as fixing it, run

```
touch /opt/redis.log
```

as root and then chown the file so the user running the redis server has write permissions.